# My JFrame wont open

Tags: java, jframe

When I try to run the code on JGrasp or Eclipse no JFrame pops up. Newish to coding but I think I did everything right.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b1;
    private JLabel lab;

    public void test()
    {

        gui();

    }

    public void gui()

    {

        f = new JFrame("This is the title of the JFrame");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        b1 = new JButton("This is the JButton");
        lab = new JLabel("This is the JLabel");

        p.add(b1);
        p.add(lab);

        f.add(p);

    }

    public static void main (String args []){

        new test();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with whiskeyspider, but your constructor shouldn't have a return type.  `public void test()` should be changed to `public test()`.

Comment: Agreed.  I think that's the main reason nothing is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setVisible(true)` last.  See [How To Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html).

```
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You should also be doing all of the GUI stuff on the Event Dispatch thread.